# Wireless network card is dectected but not working

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, drivers

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS in my HP laptop. My wireless card is not working. But, I could see wireless controller in `lspci` and `lshw -C network`. Here, I have enclosed the output.

Whether should i need to install any specific drivers?
If so, What are the drivers?

`lspci -k`:

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2190
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
03:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. Device 0036 (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 217f
```

`lshw -C network`:

```
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 07
       serial: fc:15:b4:05:02:59
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=N/A ip=192.168.12.190 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:105 ioport:1000(size=256) memory:90600000-90600fff memory:90400000-90403fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Atheros Communications Inc.
       vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:90500000-9057ffff memory:90580000-9058ffff
```

`iwconfig`:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

I don't why my wireless network is `UNCLAIMED`.

Guide me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please run:

```
lspci -nn
```

Is your wireless device 168c:0036? If so, it is not covered in 12.04 by the default driver ath9k, so install the compat-wireless suite. First, determine your kernel version:

```
uname -r
```

If your kernel is -pae, then do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.10-precise-generic-pae
```

If not, then do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.10-precise-generic
```

Then do:

```
sudo modprobe ath9k
```

Detach the ethernet and your wireless should be working.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct driver isn't loaded.

Run Additional Drivers and see if a driver pops up for you.

or

You could try upgrading to 14.04 or look [here](http://www.qca.qualcomm.com/resources/driverdownloads/)

or check with the manufacturer [here](http://www.qca.qualcomm.com/resources/driverdownloads/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, I have to install 12.04 only. what is the driver i need to use? So that, I can install it and make it work. When I see `lspci -k`, I found that kernel is not having/using any driver/module to detect the wireless.

Comment: @sat edited answer